# c++ sending image to printer , (PRINT) 

Tags: c++, windows, image, printing, mfc

this is code which i use to make image.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
bitmap.CreateBitmap(715, 844,1,1, NULL);

CDC memDC;
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
memDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);

CString SS="Sun Goes Down";
 memDC.TextOutA(1,2,SS);

        CImage image;
        image.Attach(bitmap);
        image.Save(_T("C:\\test.bmp"), Gdiplus::ImageFormatJPEG);
```

and all is ok , now all i want is to send that image to print...

i use

```
    DWORD pcchBuffer=100;

  char * pszBuffer=new char[100];

 GetDefaultPrinter(pszBuffer,&pcchBuffer);
```

again all is ok.

to get defaulet printername , for print i know  WritePrinter function, but that fonction gives argumens LPVOID buffer to print , how can i send my image to print? 
Many many Thanks!

Comment: This looks like Windows code, but since the answer is going to be OS-specific you should probably mention what OS you are targeting.

Comment: Have you find a way to do it.. Unfortunately i am also stuck in a similar workflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the image, saving it, then printing it, you should:

- Create a DC for the printer (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183521%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- Paint the image on this DC
- Write or paint whatever you want on the DC
- Close the DC

Look for all the detailed steps on MSDN.

Comment: ok , thanks! that's right,  but problem is  - i want and image and print ,  is  possble to create new CDC for print as described  and do all DRAWING as it do for image ?   
(DRAWING is large code  , and i do not want to do it and for print and for image) .  please if you can , help me!

Comment: You could first perform all the complex image drawing into a DC of a bitmap (as in your question), then save it, open a DC for the printer, and draw the bitmap in the DC of the printer.  That way, you will only have to do the complex drawing once.